# JTextArea dynamic name initiazation using array or any other method

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

please give any solution. i want to use it with dynamic name.

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    JTextArea ta[i]= new JTextArea();
    String s=""+i;
    ta[i].setText(s);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that what you want to do is rather this:

```
// Create an array of JTextArea
JTextArea[] jTextAreas = new JTextArea[10];
// Iterate on all the possible indexes
for(int i=0;i<jTextAreas.length;i++) {
    // Create a new instance of JTextArea for the current index
    jTextAreas[i] = new JTextArea();
    // Set dynamically the text
    jTextAreas[i].setText(Integer.toString(i));
}
```